# Change Default settings in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

After installing sublime text 3 on Linux, I cannot seem to change the default settings, for example:

```
 // Controls auto pairing of quotes, brackets etc
"auto_match_enabled": true,
```

I can't replace true to false. The file appears to be read-only.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Sublime Text 3 does not allow you to change default settings in the `Settings - Default` file. This is because this file gets overwritten each time the program is upgraded, losing all of your settings. To change settings, choose `Preferences -> Settings - User`, create an empty object if the file has no contents:

```
{

}
```

and put your settings in it, with a comma after each one except the last (basically, it should be valid [JSON](http://json.org)):

```json
{
    "auto_match_enabled": false
}
```

You can copy from the default file and paste into the user file.

---

Sublime Text applies settings from both your Default `.sublime-settings` files & User `.sublime-settings` files. However, any settings that exist in your `User` settings files will override those in the `Default` settings files.

This applies to both `Preferences.sublime-settings` and any plugin-specific `.sublime-settings` files.

Furthermore: project, syntax, and buffer specific settings will take precedence over a general purpose `.sublime-settings` file. For more information see [**SublimeText/Docs/Settings**](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html)

Comment: So how exactly are you suppose to change settings like remember_files and hot_exit when those can only be changed in default to take any effect? :/

Comment: @srcspider see [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/settings.html#order-of-precedence-of-sublime-settings-files) for the order of precedence Sublime uses when processing settings. `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` is processed **after** the defaults, so any setting you put in there will override the default one.

Comment: For those wondering: changes take effect as soon as you save the file. No need to restart Sublime or re-open files.

Comment: @Enteleform thanks for the edit, it's very useful information.

Comment: I don't have a 'Preferences - Settings - User' option in my SublimeText 3. Is this a file you need to create within the Sublime file structure?

Comment: @KyleVassella on OSX, you need to open the "Sublime Text" menu to find _Preferences_ and then the _Settings_ sub-menu