# How to change the color of right sidebar (miniMap) in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

There is a rectangle area in the right sidebar, showing the current code block you are in in the context of the whole file, however it is kind of difficult to see, anyone know how to make the color more obvious?

[image: as shown in the picture below]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible** to change the color of the minimap. In addition **there are also a couple of settings that you can enable to make the minimap easier to see**:

- *draw_minimap_border*: enable it to see the minimap border.
- *always_show_minimap_viewport*: makes the minimap always visible (even if the mouse is not near the minimap).

Example user settings (use menu *Preferences>Settings*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20288327/3870761) for more info about sublime user-settings file format):

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "draw_minimap_border": true
}
```

### How to change the color of the minimap?

To change the color of the minimap you should do it in your theme file. The default theme file is called *Default.sublime-theme* but this file name could be different if you are using a different downloaded theme. You need to change the value of the property *viewport_color* inside the class *minimap_control*. In order to do it you have two main options:

- **Option 1: override the values in a new file**. Create a file called *Default.sublime-theme* in your user folder (you can find your user folder using menu *Preferences>Browse-packages* and then open the folder called user). Set this content to the file, use another color values if you want, save it with fileName *Default.sublime-theme* (supposing you are using default theme), and then restart:

  ```
  [
      {
          "class": "minimap_control",
          "settings": ["always_show_minimap_viewport"],
          "viewport_color": [68, 200, 240, 96],
          "viewport_opacity": 1.0,
      },

      {
          "class": "minimap_control",
          "settings": ["!always_show_minimap_viewport"],
          "viewport_color": [68, 200, 240, 96],
          "viewport_opacity": { "target": 0.0, "speed": 4.0, "interpolation": "smoothstep" },
      },

      {
          "class": "minimap_control",
          "attributes": ["hover"],
          "settings": ["!always_show_minimap_viewport"],
          "viewport_opacity": { "target": 1.0, "speed": 20.0, "interpolation": "smoothstep" },
      },
  ]
  ```
- **Option 2: edit your theme file directly**. If you are using Linux and the default theme you usually can found *Default.sublime-theme* inside */opt/sublime_text/Packages/Theme - Default.sublime-package*. If you are using windows and the default theme you usually can find *Default.sublime-theme* inside *C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Theme - Default.sublime-package*.

---

Example results:

1. Default Minimap:

   [image: Default minimap]
2. Default minimap with option *draw_minimap_border* set to true.

   [image: Default minimap with border]
3. Minimap with custom color (*[68, 200, 240, 96]*) and border

   [image: Minimap with custom color]

---

**Edit: extra explanation** about the meaning of `"settings": ["!always_show_minimap_viewport"]` in the previous file. It means that the config group is only used if the sublime setting `always_show_minimap_viewport` value is set to `false`. On the other hand `"settings": ["always_show_minimap_viewport"]` means that the config group is only used if the sublime setting `always_show_minimap_viewport` is set to `true`.

More in detail, the first config group just sets the minimap color and makes opacity=1, so, it makes the minimap always visible, and this is only used when `always_show_minimap_viewport` is set to `true.

The last two config groups are only used when `always_show_minimap_viewport` is set to `false`. The second config-group sets the color and sets opacity value to 0.0, so it makes the minimap non visible. BUT, the third group causes the opacity value to be 1 when you hover the minimap (see the attribute in the config group), so it makes the minimap visible when you hover the mouse over it. And this happens if `always_show_minimap_viewport` is set to `false`.

Comment: This for great for Sublime Text 2; but, does anyone know how to make this work for Sublime Text 3?  Since ST3 doesn't have a Default.sublime-theme file, I copied the one from my ST2 but it's ignored.

Comment: @AtomTech I made this with ST3. If you are using Linux you usually can found _Default.sublime-theme_ inside _/opt/sublime_text/Packages/Theme - Default.sublime-package_. If you are using windows you usually can find _Default.sublime-theme_ inside _C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Theme - Default.sublime-package_. Please make me now if you have any problem doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The path you gave for Windows is correct, but if I open that file in ST3, it's encoded, so all I see are thousands of lines of 4-bit hex numbers.  I'm on Windows 8.1, ST3 64-bit portable version, build 3095 if that helps?  It's not JSON like I'd expect.

Comment: That happens because it is a zip file. I've edited my answer to add a option of making this creating a new file instead of editing the default theme file inside the zip. Take a look at option 1 to see if it helps you.

Comment: I tried option 1, and I also unzipped and edited the Theme - Default.sublime-package and restored it back with the edits, but neither worked.  Maybe this is just an issue with the latest dev build I'm using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100416/change-sublime-text-minimap-color-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-25239473)

Comment: Nice, I was trying to remember this the other day for a [__similar post__](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/highlighted-indents-in-sublime-text-3-like-notepad/18661/6) I made regarding visibility.  Just linked to your answer. Didn't know about the hover option since it wasn't in the theme I modified.

Comment: Your answers are awesome BTW, very clear & detailed. Are you on the ST forum?

Comment: You should be, seems like you know your stuff. : ) Got any plugins on PackageControl or in the works?

Comment: Nope, I have just made some plugins for stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Nice answer @sergioFC, I have two questions. 1- what are the two classes with the `!always_show_minimap_viewport` setting for? I noticed that I can comment them out, and the minimap still shows with the desired color. 2- where is the `draw_minimap_border` setting? I can't find it in your answer.

Comment: @Gabriel Thank you. I've updated the answer to add more info about where to place sublime settings and about the meaning of `!always_show_minimap_viewport`. Feel free to ask me again if something is not clear

Comment: I came here to upvote your great answer. Thank you and have a great day!