# Sublime Text 3 - how do I make the sidebar black?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I can't seem to turn the sidebar black in Sublime 3. I have downloaded a few themes but the sidebar always stays the standard grey. How do you do it?

Comment: Have you restarted Sublime Text (`command + Q`)?

Comment: Not sure if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239473/how-to-change-the-color-of-right-sidebar-in-sublime/25247517#25247517) is what you want.

Comment: Sadly not. thanks though.

Comment: Are you talking about the left sidebar (files and folders) or the right sidebar (minimap)?

Comment: I found the answer I was looking for on this question [Why do Sublime Text 3 Themes not affect the sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931448/why-do-sublime-text-3-themes-not-affect-the-sidebar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `.sublime-theme` file for the theme you are interested in changing. It's likely wrapped up in a `.sublime-package` zip file in `Installed Packages`, so first install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control, which is an indispensable tool to have if you want to do any kind of hacking on Sublime's packages, either built-in or installed via Package Control. Once the plugin has been installed, open the Command Palette and type ***`prv`*** to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options. Select **`Extract Package`**, then scroll down the list until you find the name of the theme you installed. If you're simply using the default theme, it's called **`Theme - Default`** (easy enough to remember). Finally, go to **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to bring up your `Packages` folder in your operating system's file browser - its location will vary by OS and installation type. Open the folder of your newly-extracted theme, and start editing the appropriate `.sublime-theme` file in Sublime, using JSON syntax for highlighting, if you prefer.

Now that we've got the actual file open, search for `"class": "sidebar_container"` (or just `sidebar_container`, it should be unique), and take a look at it. This is the `Default.sublime-theme` one:

```js
{
    "class": "sidebar_container",
    "layer0.tint": [80, 80, 80],
    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "layer0.draw_center": false,
    "layer0.inner_margin": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 1, 0]
},
```

while this is the one in the `Soda - Dark` theme (my personal favorite):

```js
{
    "class": "sidebar_container",
    "layer0.texture": "Theme - Soda/Soda Dark/sidebar-bg.png",
    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "layer0.inner_margin": [1, 1, 2, 1],
    "content_margin": [0, 0, 1, 0]
},
```

The key lines we're looking for are `"layer0.tint"` in Default, and `"layer0.texture"` in Soda Dark. The Default theme sets the "tint" (or color) of `layer0` (the very bottom layer, or background) at `[80, 80, 80]`, which is a list of RGB color values in decimal, with possible values ranging from 0 to 255 (`00` to `FF` in hex), and producing a dark-ish gray. On the other hand, Soda Dark uses `"layer0.texture"` and a `.png` file (you can find it and the Retina `@2X` version in the `Soda Dark` subdirectory of `Theme - Soda`) to set the background to a certain color, which happens to be just a bit lighter than `[80, 80, 80]`.

OK, that's all very interesting, but how do I change the background of my sidebar to black? The answer is simple: look in the `sidebar_container` class, and see if `layer0.tint` or `layer0.texture` is being used (hopefully they're not in there together). The easiest way to change the color is to comment out any lines defining `layer0.texture` by adding `//` as the first two characters of the line, and either add (if it's not present) or change (if it is present) the `layer0.tint` line to the following:

```js
"layer0.tint": [0, 0, 0],
```

then save the file. Now, Sublime is weird about changing themes (and sometimes color schemes). Sometimes I can make a change like this and as soon as I save the file (assuming the theme is already active in my user preferences), Sublime immediately updates all open windows, and I'm happy. Other times, it doesn't seem to do anything immediately, and I have to completely shut down Sublime and restart it to see anything. In either case, though, once you've made this simple change, the background of your sidebar should be nice and black.