# Sublime 3: Ctrl-c triggers even if no text is selected, drops text in clipboard

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using `Sublime 3083`.

Suppose I cut some text (`Ctrl-x`) in a file and then attempt to paste it somewhere else, in that same file or another one.

1. I position the cursor on the line I want to paste the text.
2. If I hit `Ctrl-v` the text is pasted with no issues.
3. But if I accidentally hit `Ctrl-c` instead, the text that was cut can no longer be pasted. It is dropped from the clipboard and I'm forced to `Ctrl-z` back to the point before the text was cut.

This happens even if *no text is selected* when hitting `Ctrl-c`.

I tested and this behaviour seems to be exclusive from `Sublime`. Is this a feature? If so, can it be disabled?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a setting in `Preferences > Settings - Default` which can change the behavior:

```
// If true, the copy and cut commands will operate on the current line
// when the selection is empty, rather than doing nothing.

"copy_with_empty_selection": false,
```

Changing it to `false` should make it so that it doesn't copy an empty selection.

Comment: That was it, thank you! What possible use can this option have? Why would you want those shortcuts to operate on empty selections?

Comment: Well, I guess if someone is lazy and doesn't want to select the entire line and copy it then the setting will do it for them by placing the cursor anywhere... :)

Comment: Ohhh I see now. Hadn't even occurred to me that it could be used to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it possible to enable this, but with a different keyboard shortcut? It seems like it would be useful in certain situations. However, I currently only ever do it by accidently hitting ctrl+c (or, even worse, ctrl+x) when I mean to push ctrl+v, and deleting my clipboard at the exact moment I was ready to paste makes me something something. Go crazy? DON'T MIND IF I DO!!

Comment: @jmorganmartin Not exactly what you want probably, but you can ctrl+L to highlight the line, then ctrl+C to copy it. It's obviously not a single command and it has the side effect of including any line break at the end, but it's built in.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your User settings:

```
"copy_with_empty_selection": false
```

---

Step-by-Step:

1. `Preferences > Settings`
2. A new window will open with 2 files:

[image]

3. In `sublime-settings -- User` (the one on the right) paste this:

   `"copy_with_empty_selection": false`

### [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20288327/1152809)

If you do it in *Default* settings it will be overwritten when sublime updates. Any changes you make to settings should be in User Settings.