# Sublime text 3 alphabets and brackets are misaligned

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3 on windows 10 and Ubuntu.

When I use sublime text 3 on Ubuntu, letters and brackets (and all the other special characters) are kind of misaligned.

---

**Windows 10:**

[image: Windows 10]

**Ubuntu:**

[image: Ubuntu]

---

While this is not a huge issue, it sometimes confuses me. 
Because of that weird positioning, hyphens and under-bars are indistinguishable.
I've google searched about this issue but couldn't find any solution. 
Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different font.

You can do this by adding:
`"font_face": "New Font Goes Here",`
to your [**User Preferences**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280159/change-default-settings-in-sublime-text-3/20288327#20288327).

Answer (score 1):

Enteleform's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37041959/1426065) is correct, you should change your font. I'd recommend installing the [`fonts-liberation`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-liberation) package by running

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-liberation
```

and using

```
"font_face": "Liberation Mono"
```

in your User preferences. I've been using it for years, and I love it. It was designed so that each character is unambiguous, meaning you can easily tell the difference between `0` and `O`, `l` and `1`, etc. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Liberation Mono]

To keep things consistent, you can also download the Liberation TTF font files [here](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/) for Windows. Decompress the archive, then right-click on each TTF file and select the "Install Font" option.