# Copying text from VirtualBox Debian guest to Windows 7 host adds lines

Tags: debian, sublimetext2, virtualbox, clipboard, windows-7-x64

I am running VirtualBox 5.0.5 on a 64-bit Windows 7 host with guest 64-bit Debian 7.  The clipboard is bidirectional.

When I copy text from Sublime Text 2 on the guest and paste it into any editor on the host, an extra newline is added to every line.  It does not seem to occur when copying from other sources.  This would somehow make sense if it were adding carriage returns for Windows' sake, i.e. changing "\n" to "\r\n", but it's not, it's changing "\n" to "\n\n".

I get around this by pasting the text into Notepad++ then using search-and-replace to replace every "\n\n" with "\n", but I've finally decided I'm tired of doing this.

Is there something I can do about this to avoid the extra newlines?

**Update**

I wrote a small Windows program to examine the Windows clipboard, and it looks like the clipboard is actually replacing each individual line ending with "\r\r\n", no matter what `default_line_ending` is set to, and no matter which line endings the source document actually contains.  Most Windows programs simply interpret "\r\r\n" as two lines and put two of whatever format is expected; I have Notepad++ configured to use Unix line endings by default, so it was converting "\r\r\n" to "\n\n".

**Update 1.5**

Example case:  Copying this from Sublime Text 2 in the guest (with "\n" as line ending)

```
cat
on
mat
```

becomes in the Windows clipboard (with hexadecimal and decimal interpretation):

```
c 0x63 99
a 0x61 97
t 0x74 116
? 0x0D 13
? 0x0D 13
? 0x0A 10
o 0x6F 111
n 0x6E 110
? 0x0D 13
? 0x0D 13
? 0x0A 10
m 0x6D 109
a 0x61 97
t 0x74 116
```

**Update 2**

I wrote a Sublime Text 2 plug-in to do a similar test.  Copying this text in the guest

```
cat
on
mat
```

puts into the guest clipboard (with decimal interpretation):

```
c 99
a 97
t 116
? 10
o 111
n 110
? 10
m 109
a 97
t 116
```

So according to Sublime Text 2, nothing is amiss, yet when Windows accesses the clipboard containing text from Sublime Text 2, the messed up end lines are retrieved.  This doesn't happen when I copy text from other sources on the host or guest.

Another phenomenon is that if I have text highlighted anywhere in the guest, if I press Ctrl+C anywhere in the guest or host, the guest's highlight goes away.  Could this be related to the main issue?  Or perhaps both of these are a symptoms of an underlying issue?

**Update 3**

It looks like Sublime Text 2 is always sending "\n" to the clipboard (before the jumble), even when I have `default_line_ending` set to `windows` and I copy from a text file that has "\r\n" for line endings.  I also noticed that in the Windows-style text file, when I highlight text, each line ending only counts for 1 character instead of 2 when Sublime Text 2 reports "x lines, y characters selected."  I would guess Sublime Text 2 has some aggressive line ending management and it's not communicating properly with the clipboard.

I don't know if this is of any use, but if I query the Windows Clipboard for its formats, it reports

```
 1 TEXT
 7 OEMTEXT
13 UNICODETEXT
16 LOCALE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an all-new virtual machine guest running Debian 9.  I installed Sublime Text 2 then Sublime Text 3 on it and configured them as close as I can to Sublime Text 2 on my old guest.

Copying text from Sublime Text 3 on the new guest to the Windows 7 host does *not* have this issue, while copying text from Sublime Text 2 on the same new guest *still does*.  I'm chalking this up to a bug between Sublime Text 2 and Windows which was resolved somewhere in Sublime Text 3's revisions.

**Solution: Upgrade to Sublime Text 3.**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `default_line_ending` setting in your [**Preferences**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280159/change-default-settings-in-sublime-text-3/20288327#20288327) file.

```
{
  // Determines what character(s) are used to terminate each line in new files.
  // Valid values are 'system' (whatever the OS uses), 'windows' (CRLF) and
  // 'unix' (LF only).
  "default_line_ending": "system",
}
```

---

Updating that setting will only affect new files.

If you find that it solves your issue, the following plugins may be useful:

- [**Line Endings Unify**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Line%20Endings%20Unify)
- [**RawLineEdit**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RawLineEdit)

Comment: I've tried changing the setting `default_line_ending` from `system` to `unix` and `windows`, but in all cases I'm still getting extra lines when copying text from Sublime Text 2 and pasting it into Windows.

I have saved files in Sublime Text 2 then opened them in a hex editor and confirmed that the files are being saved with the correct line endings, so I doubt either those plug-ins would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple plugin that allows you to copy any selected text to the clipboard while replacing its line breaks with those of your choosing.

---

Save this as:
`Packages/ReplaceLineBreaksToClipboard/ReplaceLineBreaksToClipboard.py`

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

valid_LineBreak   = "\n"
invalid_LineBreak = "\r"

class ReplaceLinebreaksToClipboardCommand( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):
    def run( self, edit ):

        selections     = self.view.sel()
        selectionCount = len( selections )

        if selectionCount == 0:
            return

        clipboardText = ""

        for index in range( 0, selectionCount ):

            clipboardText += self.view.substr( selections[ index ] )

            if index < selectionCount - 1:
                clipboardText += valid_LineBreak

        clipboardText = clipboardText.replace( invalid_LineBreak, valid_LineBreak )

        sublime.set_clipboard( clipboardText )
```

---

Set the `valid_LineBreak` & `invalid_LineBreak` values as needed ( *@ lines 3 & 4* ).

All instances of `invalid_LineBreak` will be replaced by `valid_LineBreak`.

---

Add your preferred key-binding to execute the `replace_linebreaks_to_clipboard` command by including the following code in your user `sublime-keymap` file.

```
{
    "keys": [ "ctrl+shift+alt+c" ],
    "command": "replace_linebreaks_to_clipboard",
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the plug-in, but it didn't work.  To verify that I'd set it up correctly, I set `valid_LineBreak` to other printing characters such as "X", and the line break was indeed replaced with "X" -- but only if `invalid_LineBreak` was set to what Sublime Text 2 was *supposed* to be generating ("\n") and not the unwanted line break found in the clipboard ("\r").  No matter what I did, Windows was still reading newlines in the clipboard as "\r\r\n".

There must be some sort of weird disjointed connection between Sublime Text 2 and the VirtualBox clipboard.

Comment: @AufbeschissenerKunde: Weird indeed... Maybe the VirtualBox clipboard prefers `\r`? Did you try using `\r` as `valid_LineBreak` & `\n` as `invalid_LineBreak` ?