# Why there is so much white-space on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

Coming out of nothing every time I save, delete or add a new line of code, there is white-space so I have to be deleting empty-space.

Like this

[image]

See the yellow thing? What can I do about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
```

to your [**User Settings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280159/change-default-settings-in-sublime-text-3/20288327#20288327) file.