# sublime text 3: key-bound commands for jumping to next and previous space

Tags: sublimetext3

In vim, `f<space>` and `F<space>` move the cursor forward to the next space and backward to the previous space, respectively.

Is there a command in Sublime Text 3 that does the same? If so, please demonstrate its use in a key binding.

Comment: Sublime text has vintage mode and support f/F just like vim,  doesn't it?

Comment: @Jimmyliu Thank you for pointing out Vintage but I don't want to get into vim-style editing where I've got to switch between modes. I use Sublime for a reason. :-)

Comment: I see, good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the following code to:
`/Packages/MoveToSpace/MoveToSpace.py`

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class MoveToSpaceCommand( sublime_plugin.TextCommand ):
    def run( self, edit, mode ):

        view = self.view
        selections = self.view.sel()

        if len( selections ) == 0:
            return

        newSelections = []

        for selection in selections:

            spacePoint = None

            if mode.lower() == "forward":

                spacePoint = self.view.find( "[^ ] " , selection.end() ).a

                if spacePoint != -1:
                    newSelections.append( sublime.Region( spacePoint + 1, spacePoint + 1 ) )

            elif mode.lower() == "backward":

                spaceRegions = self.view.find_all( " [^ ]")
                spaceRegion_Count = len( spaceRegions )

                for index in range( 0, spaceRegion_Count ):
                    if spaceRegions[ index ].b < selection.begin():
                        spacePoint = spaceRegions[ index ].a
                    elif spaceRegions[ index ].b >= selection.begin() \
                    and  spacePoint != None:
                        newSelections.append( sublime.Region( spacePoint + 1, spacePoint + 1 ) )
                        break

        if len( newSelections ) > 0:
            view.sel().clear()
            view.sel().add_all( newSelections )
```

---

Save the following code to:
`/Packages/MoveToSpace/Default.sublime-keymap`

```json
[

    {
        "keys":    [ "ctrl+shift+=" ],
        "command": "move_to_space",
        "args":    { "mode": "forward" },
    },

    {
        "keys":    [ "ctrl+shift+-" ],
        "command": "move_to_space",
        "args":    { "mode": "backward" },
    },

]
```

---

Included key-bindings are:

- <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Plus</kbd> to move to the next space
- <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Minus</kbd> to move to the previous space

You can change the key-bindings to suit your preference.

Comment: ST2? It simply doesn't work, e.g., `File "./MoveToSpace.py", line 20, in run
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'`. For another example: `File "./MoveToSpace.py", line 38, in run
    view.sel().add_all(newSelections)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    RegionSet.add_all(RegionSet, list)
did not match C++ signature:
    add_all(SelectionSet {lvalue}, SelectionSet)
`

Comment: Also note: ST2 rejects trailing commas before closing braces/brackets. There are three of them in the `Default.sublime-keymap` above. 3 < 6 so I can't make the edit -- SO insists edits be at least 6 chars.

Comment: I wrote + tested on ST3. Idk the API differences but you could probably adapt the code pretty easily.  Any reason you're still on ST2?  It's [**pretty much deprecated**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/3) at this point...

Comment: Good point. :) Been heads down I guess. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Your solution works for me now that I'm on ST3. Updated question to reference ST3 instead of ST2.

Comment: This is terrific! Thanks! A little note for users: it doesn't consider a newline a space

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd> moves the caret by word boundaries, including spaces.

You can alter the characters that dictate word boundaries in your [**User Settings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280159/change-default-settings-in-sublime-text-3/20288327#20288327) by editing the `word_separators` value.

---

Sublime Text also has [**Vintage Mode**](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/vintage.html), which emulates many of VIM's functionalities including:
`l, h, j, k, W, w, e, E, b, B, alt+w, alt+W, $, ^, %, 0, G, gg, f, F, t, T, ^f, ^b, H, M, L`

Comment: As you point out, `ctrl+left/right` doesn't do exactly what `f/F<space>` does. Is it possible to specify `word_separators` for just one key binding? If so, per my question, could you demonstrate how to do this?

Comment: @kkurian: You cannot, `word_separators` can only be set on a [ global | syntax | project | view ] context. Did you try Vintage mode? I'm not a Vim user, but it says it has the `f` & `F` functionalities. As well as: `l, h, j, k, W, w, e, E, b, B, alt+w, alt+W, $, ^, %, 0, G, gg, f, F, t, T, ^f, ^b, H, M, and L`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Vintage but I don't want to get into vim-style editing where I've got to switch between modes. I use Sublime for a reason. :-)